# VBA Excel, replace numbers and specific chars with blanks

Tags: excel, vba

I have several things I need to do to clean up a file that costs us 6 hours monthly.  I have a VBA code that clears numbers in a row, but I also have several specific character strings such as AST, TL, TYC and symbols like ~~ _ that I want to integrate into the VBA to clear at the same time.  I am new to VBA and would like some insight or an example of how to integrate that.  We get a 8,000 entry csv file and essentially clean up any numbers and additional characters for the names.  Thank you for your assistance!

```
Sub clear()
s = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
For Each r In Selection
    v = r.Value
    For i = 0 To 9
        v = Replace(v, s(i), "")
    Next
    r.Value = v
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the strings to the Array: `s = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "AST", "TL", "TYC")`. And fix the loop so it loops through everything in the Array

Comment: Goto Developer > Record Macro, do your stuff (ctrl+H to replace any value with what you want), replace ALL every time, repeat as many times as you like (for all replacements) > stop and save macro > edit macro (Alt+F11) and add any replacements for characters that are hard to get while recording (code() and char() may help a lot here)...     Assign to macro and run when needed...

Comment: Thank you both so much!  I updated the array and fixed the loop, but excel kept erroring out so I did go with the recording to avoid that.  I will be saving this info for future projects :)